# Why does "不一一" mean "I won't go into details (in letters)?

Tags: etymology

[CUHK appears to lack a listing for 不一一](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/searchExplain.php?explain=%E4%B8%8D%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%80).

[image]

[*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary), p 74.

Answer (score 1):

不: not

一一: one by one

不一一: not one by one, namely not go into details.

Examples:

- 在此就不一一介绍了。
- 本系统还有许多其它的功能，这里不一一列举出来了。

Note that you shouldn't use "不一一" with nothing behind it.

Answer (score 0):

一一 is short for 一個接一個 (one after another/ one by one)

一一介紹 = introducing items one by one

一一解釋 = explaining one thing after another

一一詳述 = item by item describing in details

不一一介紹 = not introduce items one by one

不一一解釋 = not explaining one thing after another = not explaining everything

不一一詳述 = not item by item describing in details

- You cannot just say 不一一 (not one by one) and not adding a verb after it.
- The dictionary's definition of 一一 should be "one by one (adv)"
- 不一一 shouldn't even be listed. It is like listing "wonder" and then add another entry for "not wonder"